# ASP .NET application hangs with IIS 8 and Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: .net, api, iis, request, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an issue that i can't identify it from where it's happening , so let me introduce the issue in bullet points format :

- Am deploying a .NET Framework application , separated into frontend
  and backend part into iis in a windows 2012 server .
- The frontend part is communicating with backend via API's ; ( the
  frontend part is built using eviromnement to refer the backend like
  http://myapp.domain.com/api ... )  , so everything was running
  smoothly
- I tried to migrate to HTTPS for the endpoints ; so i made a new
  frontend build ( Angular ) that points to
  https://myapp.domain.com/api ... of course with making successefully
  an SSL certificate to establish communication .
- The app is working smoothly , but suddenly , i see hangs , and
  exactly from from worker processes , and for the appropriate app pool
  for backend part , i see the accumlation of request and not
  connecting anymore , i can't get any response from the deployed
  backend any more , even seperately when using POSTMAN !
- The app can get back working only if i restart the server , note that
  The CPU is not full , and memory also ; so threads of the app can
  find place to continue and have place to be executed.

Am using iis 8 and windows server 2012 R2 , and i would be so gratefull , if i get clear explanation about the root cause , contributing to the hangs and stopping backend.

This is the result of theworker process for the app pool :

[image]

Comment: You should either use a performance profiler or WinDbg to analyze (as Tess documented at https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex). Nobody can help much without accessing this server.

Comment: same question: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/882914/asp-net-application-hangs-with-iis-8-and-windows-s.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/882914/asp-net-application-hangs-with-iis-8-and-windows-s.html).